# HotChocolate mutation input type uses int instead of ID

Tags: graphql, hotchocolate, strawberryshake

I am new to HotChocolate and GraphQL as a whole and am trying to grasp on enabling Nodes and/or Relay support for my GraphQL API. Currently using HotChocolate v12.

Context
I am trying to create a mutation that updates an entity (*Client* in this example). I am using code-first approach here and have the following:

1. An input record/class is defined as follows:

```
public record UpdateClientInput([ID(nameof(Client))] int Id, string Code, string Name, string Subdomain);
```

2. The mutation function which returns the payload class:

```
[UseAppDbContext]
public async Task<UpdateClientPayload> UpdateClientAsync(UpdateClientInput input, [ScopedService] AppDbContext context)
{
    var client = await context.Set<Client>().FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == input.Id);
                    
    // cut for brevity
                    
    return new UpdateClientPayload(client);
}
```

3. I have enabled support for Nodes by adding this in the services configuration:

```
builder.Services
    .AddGraphQLServer()
        .AddQueryType(d => d.Name("Query"))
        .AddMutationType(d => d.Name("Mutation"))
        // removed others for brevity      
        .AddGlobalObjectIdentification()
        .AddQueryFieldToMutationPayloads();
```

But yet when I browse the API using Banana Cake Pop, the UpdateClientInput object in the schema definition still uses *int* instead of the *ID!* (see screenshot below). So the GraphQL client I am using (Strawberry Shake) generates the input object that does not use the *ID!* type. Am I missing something here?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So to solve this problem, this was actually a change in HotChocolate v12 where records should use the [property: ID] instead of the [ID] attribute. That change is found here https://chillicream.com/docs/hotchocolate/api-reference/migrate-from-11-to-12#records.

What I did is to change the record declaration from:

```
public record UpdateClientInput([ID(nameof(Client))] int Id, string Code, string Name, string Subdomain);
```

to

```
public record UpdateClientInput([property: ID] int Id, string Code, string Name, string Subdomain);
```

that generated this input object as:
[image]